# Embeded Object with @Id in morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

We're adding revision history to our app and we're running into some issues around embedding the archival document in our history object. Our state looks this:

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity("bookOrder")
@Converters({DateTimeConverter.class, LocalDateConverter.class})
public class BookOrderState {
    @Id
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    @Getter
    private final BookOrderStatus status;

    @Getter private Long version;
...
```

and our history object looks like:

```
@ToString
@Entity("bookOrderHistory")
@Converters(DateTimeConverter.class)
public class BookOrderStateHistory {

    @Id
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    private DateTime createdDate;

    @Getter
    private BookOrderState bookOrder;
...
```

As we update an order we grab its current state from the db wrap it in a history object that gets its own id and timestamp and save both the new `bookOrderStateHistory` and the updated `bookOrderState` to the db. This process writes correctly, but on retrieval, we end up with multiple unique history objects that all have the same `bookOrderState`. We traced this down to the `@Id` on the BookOrderState. Since many history objects will have state objects with the same `_id` (but with differences in the actual state of the object), morphia appears to assume that they all should get the same state object. We've hacked together a way to intercept the embedded state object and switch its `_id` to just `id` on writes (and the opposite way on reads), but this feels wrong.

**Tl;dr:** Is there a simple way to have prevent morphia from `id -> _id`'ing an object when it's inside another document?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing pretty much exactly the same thing using Morphia and haven't run into any issues.  I don't see it in your code above but if the "bookOrder" attribute is annotated with @Reference then you would see the behavior you're describing.  It seems like Morphia defaults to @Embedded if you don't put @Reference so you should be ok.
I have a simple class called "Snapshot" that I use for storing history of an object:

```
@Entity("snapshots")
public class Snapshot<T>
{
  @Id
  protected ObjectId id;

  @Embedded
  protected T data;
}
```

Whenever an object changes I create a Snapshot of it and save the snapshot to the database.  Using the following simple test case I seem to get the correct behavior:

```
Point pt = new Point();
pt.setLatitude( 40.0 );
pt.setLongitude( 40.0 );

ds.save( pt ); //ds is Datastore

Snapshot<Point> ts1 = new Snapshot<Point>();
ts1.setData( pt );
ds.save( ts1 );

pt.setLatitude( 50.0 );
ds.save( pt );

pt = ds.get( Point.class, pt.getId() );

Snapshot<Point> ts2 = new Snapshot<Point>();
ts2.setData( pt );

ds.save( ts2 );

ts1 = ds.get( Snapshot.class, ts1.getId() );
ts2 = ds.get( Snapshot.class, ts2.getId() );

Assert.assertEquals( 40.0, ts1.getData().getLatitude() );
Assert.assertEquals( 50.0, ts2.getData().getLatitude() );

Assert.assertEquals( 40.0, ts1.getData().getLongitude() );
Assert.assertEquals( 40.0, ts2.getData().getLongitude() );
```

The Point in both Snapshots have the same ObjectId as the original Point object but the Point in "ts2" has a latitude of 50.0 while the Point in "ts1" has a latitude of 40.0.  ObjectId values are assigned when the object is inserted into the database and never change (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs).

Sorry I'm not sure exactly what your issue is but wanted to let you know that I'm doing something very similar and it seems to be working.  Maybe try adding the @Embedded annotation to "bookOrder" in BookOrderStateHistory?

Good luck!